# Dynamic Question and Answer form

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am currently creating a lwc form dynamically using two custom objects namely Questions & Answers. Question being the master and answer being the detail. I am creating the questions and answers based on the query I am getting from an apex class. I am able to display the questions in a correct order but how do I display the required combobox value separately according to the question linked.

**formComponent.html**

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Checklist">
    <div class="slds-section slds-is-open">
        <h3 class="slds-section__title slds-theme_shade">
            <span class="slds-truncate slds-var-p-horizontal_small" title="Section Title">Account Executive Questions</span>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <lightning-layout class="slds-var-p-around_medium" multiple-rows>
        <lightning-layout-item size="4">
            <template for:each={data} for:item="question">
                <lightning-combobox
                key={question.Id}
                name="progress"
                label={question.Name}
                options={options}
                onchange={handleChange} ></lightning-combobox>
            </template>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
</lightning-card>
```

**formComponent.js**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import GetQuestionnare from '@salesforce/apex/ChecklistQuestionarre.getQuestionarre';

export default class OpportunityChecklist extends LightningElement {
    data;
    error;
    options=[];

    connectedCallback(){
    GetQuestionnare().then((result) =>{
        this.data = result;
        this.answers = result.map((item) => item.Answers__r);
        console.log(" ~ file: opportunityChecklist.js:13 ~ OpportunityChecklist ~ GetQuestionnare ~ this.answers:", JSON.stringify(this.answers))
        this.options = this.data.flatMap(item =>
            item.Answers__r.map(answer => ({ label: answer.Name, value: answer.Name, score:answer.Score__c}))
          )
        console.log(" ~ file: opportunityChecklist.js:17 ~ OpportunityChecklist ~ GetQuestionnare ~ this.options:", JSON.stringify(this.options))
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.data));
    }).catch((error)=>{
        this.error = error;
    })
    }
}
```

**QuestionarreController**

```
public with sharing class ChecklistQuestionarre {
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Question__c> getQuestionarre(){
    try {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Name, Score__c FROM Answers__r) FROM Question__c];
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

**Currently the question and answer are appearing like this**

[image]

[image]

I want Sample options to be for question 1 and Yes No to be for question 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you're keeping separate arrays for questions and answers. The data came in correct form from apex, it was already linked, so there's no need to divide it.

```
this.data = result.map(question => (
   ({
       label: question.Name,
       key: question.Id,
       options: question.Answers__r.map(answer => ({ label: answer.Name, value: answer.Id, score: answer.Score__c }))
   })
));
```

This way you'll keep the answers with its question only.

```
   <template for:each={data} for:item="question">
      <lightning-combobox
            key={question.key}
            name="progress"
            label={question.label}
            options={question.options}
            onchange={handleChange}>
      </lightning-combobox>
  </template>
```

Comment: Overthought a bit too much I guess. Thanks Sachin!